# How to implement Swift iOS Client Certificate Authentication using .pfx file?

Tags: ios, certificate, signature, private-key, pfx

I've been doing a lot of research about how to handle a .pfx file in Swift, I'm using a base64 string certificate data to convert it to .pfx and then get the private key to sign and make a Signature.

all answers I found are a bit old. I tried this old framework but it didn't work.
https://github.com/chilkatsoft/Chilkat-ObjectiveC-XCode-Sample

```
func chilkatTest() {
let bd = CkoBinData()

var success: Bool = bd.LoadFile("qa_data/pfx/cert_test123.pfx")
if success != true {
    print("Failed to load PFX file.")
    return
}

// Get the bytes contained in the PFX in base64 format:
var strBase64: String? = bd.GetEncoded("base64")

// The base64 looks like this:  "MIIbEAIBAzCCGswGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCGr0Eghq5MIIatTCCBg..."
print("\(strBase64!)")

let pfx = CkoPfx()

// Load the PFX from the base64 string
var password: String? = "test123"
success = pfx.LoadPfxEncoded(strBase64, encoding: "base64", password: password)
if success != true {
    print("\(pfx.LastErrorText)")
    return
}

print("success")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to download the latest version of the Chilkat iOS library from https://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ios.asp

The Chilkat GitHub projects can become out-of-date w.r.t. the version of the Chilkat lib that is present.  As you can see here:

[image: GitHub screenshot]

The sample source code in the GitHub project is still OK, but just make sure to update the dylib from the chilkatsoft.com downloads web pages..

Comment: Yes, I used this version, but are you sure it's working on the latest Xcode versions?  mine is 13.4 and still doesn't work. 

it keeps giving me this error below, first I tried to import the only libchilkatIos, then I tried to import all the ios files to make sure all the architectures are included, the last thing I did was to follow the note says "create one universal lib for device architectures, and one for simulator architectures", I created tow and still give me this error :
- library not found for -lchilkatIos.